# How To Extract Password Protected Rar File Using Patool On Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unrar

I have installed patool on Google Colab. The patool command works file with:

```
patoolib.extract_archive("/content/drive/My Drive/File_name.part1.rar", outdir="/content/drive/My Drive/Folder/")`
```

After it's sucessfully finished, it has extracted 10 part zip files.

But when I am trying to extract those 10 files, it returns errors, and is asking for a password. I do know the password and whenever I give the password, it says "program aborted".

Comment: What API are you using to extract the zip files?  Python's `zipfile` module supports a password parameter:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Comment: Also check out 7zip (7z), the world's greatest tool for unarchiving a crazy variety of file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 7z, you can use

```
! 7z e -pPASSWORD "path/to/file.zip"
```

to extract a file with password.

Answer (score 0):

`patool` can handle password protected archives. You only need to add verbosity=1 as shown:

```
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive(r'your file path', outdir=r"folder path", verbosity=1)
```

now, cmd opened in new window like this and asked you to enter the password:

[image]

if you have other files in it, it asked you again. you can press 'A' to apply this to all files in it like this:

[image]

I hope this help you.